# Function which loops through ID's and assigns datetimepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, datetimepicker

I am trying to write a loop which goes over 30 elements and assigns a *datetimepicker* to each one.

Currently, this is what I use to create a *datetimepicker* for one specific element:

```
var dateToday = new Date(); 
$(function() {
    $( "#Test1" ).datetimepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        stepMinute: 15,
        timeFormat: "hh:mm TT",
        minDate: dateToday

    });
});
```

Now, I have 30 elements which all follow the same naming pattern. I.e. #Test1 to #Test30.

This is what I tried as a loop but it's not working:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  var testing = document.getElementById("Test").val();
  var count = parseInt(req.value)
       for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
       console.log($("#Test" + i));
        $("#Test" + i).datetimepicker({
          dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
          numberOfMonths: 1,
          stepMinute: 15,
          timeFormat: "hh:mm TT",
          minDate: dateToday
   });
});
```

HTML code:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Number</th>
</tr>
<tr class="row1">
  <td class="description1">
  <div id="test1"> 
  <!-- This is a textbox so I'm just using a DIV as an example -->
  </div>
  </td>

  <td class="number1">
  <div id="no1"> 

  </div>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr class="row2">

<td class="description2">
  <div id="test2"> 
  <!-- This is a textbox so I'm just using a DIV as an example -->
  </div>
  </td>

  <td class="number2">
  <div id="no2"> 
  </div>
  </td>

</tr>
<tr>
</table>
```

I'm sure there's something I'm missing in my attempt at writing this loop.

Comment: `its not working` what happens? Have you confirmed the count var is available when the loop starts and is set to 30?

Comment: Currently nothing happens. It's not running. I'll have a look in the console.

Comment: provide your html as well

Comment: I will do so. Give me 5 mins

Comment: I've added the HTML in an edit on the original post.